# ValueError: number of bits must be greater than zero

Tags: python-3.x, random

I am trying to write a script about pagerank.Below is my script:

```
from scipy import *
from numpy import linalg as LA
import pickle
import random
import operator

def new_pagerank_step(current_page, N, d, links):

    if random.random() < 1 - d:
        next_page = random.randint(0, N)

    else:
        next_page = random.choice(links[current_page])

    return next_page




def pagerank_wikipedia_demo():
    with open("wikilinks.pickle", "rb") as f:
        titles, links = pickle.load(f)
    current_page = 2
    T = 100000
    N = len(titles)
    d = 0.4
    Result = {}
    result = []
    for i in range(T):

        result.append(current_page)

        current_page = new_pagerank_step(current_page, N, d, links)

pagerank_wikipedia_demo()
```

However, when I run this script, I get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/random.py", line 249, in choice
    i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/random.py", line 225, in _randbelow
    r = getrandbits(k)          # 0 <= r < 2**k
ValueError: number of bits must be greater than zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "markov1.py", line 141, in <module>
    pagerank_wikipedia_demo()
  File "markov1.py", line 135, in pagerank_wikipedia_demo
    current_page = new_pagerank_step(current_page, N, d, links)
  File "markov1.py", line 113, in new_pagerank_step
    next_page = random.choice(links[current_page])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/random.py", line 251, in choice
    raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence')
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
```

I do not understand the meaning of the ValueError. And for IndexError, I know it means the links[current_page] is empty but from my code, I can not see why the links[current_page] can be an empty list.

Answer (score 2):

This error is thrown because you somehow provide empty list to random.choices. Try:

```
random.choice([])
```

and you will see the same error.

I do not know your initial data. But I would look whether you might have empty link lists there and if so, to test it in code and design what you need to do in such case.

Answer (score 1):

Just be aware that `random.randint(0, N)` returns some `x` such that `0 <= x <= N`

Comment: Maybe you could print more debug information to locate where the exception occurs, and see around whether there are variables with unexpected value.